# Analyse structure from memory dump

Tags: debugging, memory-dump, openssl

I'm trying to extract master key from OpenSSL 1.0.2l (statically linked without debug symbols).

I'm using x64dbg, I was able to locate `int SSL_connect(SSL *s)` method, so I have a breakpoint there (the breakpoint gets hit). In the result, I have a pointer to `SSL` parameter that contains `SSL_SESSION *session` member, in which the master key is located.

The `SSL` pointer points me the following place in dump:
[image]

Is there any easy way to find my poiner to `SSL_SESSION *session` member here? Any other tool suggestions?

Useful links to OpenSSL source code:

[`int SSL_connect(SSL *s)`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/ssl/ssl_lib.c#L1002)

[`SSL` structure](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/ssl/ssl.h#L1422)

[`SSL_SESSION *session` member in `SSL`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/ssl/ssl.h#L1539)

[`SSL_SESSION` structure](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/ssl/ssl.h#L505)

Comment: Try looking at pykd. See [this](https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd/-/wikis/API-Reference#getTypeFromSource)

Comment: @sudhacker does pykd work on x64dbg  i wasn't aware of that

Comment: @blabb OP was looking for suggestions to other tools too.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the x64dbg methods to add a custom type:

1. You can do this using a combination of these [commands](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/commands/types/index.html):

- DataUnknown
- DataByte/db
- DataWord/dw
- DataDword/dw
- DataFword
- DataQword/dq
- DataTbyte
- DataOwordD
- DataMmword
- DataXmmword
- DataYmmword
- DataFloat/DataReal4/df
- DataDouble/DataReal8
- DataLongdouble/DataReal10
- DataAscii/da
- DataUnicode/du
- DataCode/dc
- DataJunk
- DataMiddle
- AddType
- AddStruct
- AddUnion
- AddMember
- AppendMember
- AddFunction
- AddArg
- AppendArg
- SizeofType
- VisitType
- ClearTypes
- RemoveType
- EnumTypes
- LoadTypes
- ParseTypes

2. Create a type definition in types [JSON](https://gist.github.com/mrexodia/e949ab26d5986a5fc1fa4944ac68147a#file-types-json) example:

{
"types": [
{
"type": "unsigned int",
"name": "DWORD"
},
{
"type": "_FILETIME*",
"name": "LPFILETIME"
}
],
"structs": [
{
"name": "ST",
"members": [
{
"type": "char",
"name": "a",
"arrsize": 0,
"offset": -1
},
{
"type": "int",
"name": "y",
"arrsize": 0,
"offset": -1
}
]
},
{
"name": "_FILETIME",
"members": [
{
"type": "DWORD",
"name": "dwLoDateTime"
},
{
"type": "DWORD",
"name": "dwHighDateTime"
}
]
},
{
"name": "BLUB",
"members": [
{
"type": "short",
"name": "c"
},
{
"type": "int",
"name": "d",
"arrsize": 2
}
]
},
{
"name": "TEST",
"members": [
{
"type": "int",
"name": "a"
},
{
"type": "char",
"name": "b"
},
{
"type": "BLUB",
"name": "e"
},
{
"type": "int",
"name": "f"
}
]
},
{
"name": "POINTEE",
"members": [
{
"type": "int",
"name": "n"
},
{
"type": "TEST",
"name": "t"
}
]
},
{
"name": "POINTER",
"members": [
{
"type": "int",
"name": "x"
},
{
"type": "POINTEE*",
"name": "next"
},
{
"type": "int",
"name": "y"
}
]
},
{
"name": "LIST_ENTRY",
"members": [
{
"type": "int",
"name": "x"
},
{
"type": "LIST_ENTRY*",
"name": "next"
},
{
"type": "int",
"name": "y"
}
]
},
{
"name": "STRINGTEST",
"members": [
{
"type": "const char*",
"name": "str"
},
{
"type": "const wchar_t*",
"name": "wstr"
}
]
}
],
"unions": [
{
"name": "UT",
"members": [
{
"type": "char",
"name": "a"
},
{
"type": "short",
"name": "b"
},
{
"type": "int",
"name": "c"
},
{
"type": "long long",
"name": "d"
}
]
}
],
"functions": [
{
"rettype": "int",
"callconv": "cdecl",
"noreturn": false,
"name": "strcasecmp",
"arguments": [
{
"type": "const char*",
"name": "s1"
},
{
"type": "const char*",
"name": "s2"
}
]
}
]
}

3. Load a [simple C header definition](https://gist.github.com/mrexodia/e949ab26d5986a5fc1fa4944ac68147a#file-context32-h) of the type

Once a type is imported you can use [VisitType](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/commands/types/VisitType.html) cmd to view it.
Additional info:
[x64dbg type system](https://x64dbg.com/blog/2016/12/04/type-system.html)
[Weekly Digest 14 - Types](https://x64dbg.com/blog/2016/11/27/weekly-digest-14.html#types)